# import data files in RStudio with variable sized headers

Tags: rstudio, rcurl, data-import

I have a list of input files in the following format:

```
student name
student grade
student extracurricular 1
student extracurricular n
---------------------------------------
course1 1st_semester_grade 2nd_semester_grade
course2 1st_semester_grade 2nd_semester_grade
```

I was using RCurl to import this data from the web. Each file is in a different url.
I want to discard everything above the "----" and just load all the course/grade info into a table.  Is there a way to do this on import? Since each student may have a variable number of extracurriculars I can't just discard the first "n" rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the variable length header is not really that long i'm just going to read in the whole page and do a strsplit to get rid of everything above the dotted line.